# Perform filter on expanded entity with SAP Cloud SDK

Tags: java, s4sdk, sap-cloud-sdk

So this might be an easy one, but I somehow can't wrap my head around it.
I am trying to find a business partner by its e-mail address using the SAP Cloud SDK.

This is what I have so far:

```java
final List<BusinessPartner> businessPartners = new DefaultBusinessPartnerService()
                        .getAllBusinessPartner()
                        .select(BusinessPartner.BUSINESS_PARTNER,
                                BusinessPartner.TO_BUSINESS_PARTNER_ADDRESS
                                        .select(BusinessPartnerAddress.TO_EMAIL_ADDRESS
                                                .select(AddressEmailAddress.SEARCH_EMAIL_ADDRESS)))
                        .filter(AddressEmailAddress.SEARCH_EMAIL_ADDRESS.eq(email)) //something like this?
                        .top(10)
                        .execute();
```

Now, how can I perform a filter operation on the expanded entity `AddressEmailAddress`? The one I  came up with obviously doesn't. I have troubles navigating to the expanded entity using the fluent API.

Any ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not possible to _filter_ on _expanded_ entities for SAP OData V2 service endpoints. In your case, I would recommend using `service.getAllAddressEmailAddress()` and filter on the Email directly, then evaluate the found _AddressId_ property, repeat the same step for `BusinessPartnerAddress` to resolve _BusinessPartner_ by filtering for _AddressId_.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Thank you for your suggestion, it worked out fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Since my proposal worked for you. Let me rephrase the comment as answer.*

Unfortunately it's not possible to *filter* on *expanded* entities for SAP OData V2 service endpoints. A fallback strategy would be to directly query for the "filtered" item in the entity collection (*leaf*) and run additional OData requests to traverse to your original entity (*root*).

In your case, I would recommend querying directly for the `AddressEmailAddress`, to resolve *BusinessPartnerAddress* by the *AddressId*. Next step is to resolve `BusinessPartner` by the *businessPartner* field, e.g.

```
public List<BusinessPartner> getBusinessPartnersByEmail(
    @Nonnull BusinessPartnerService service,
    @Nonnull String email
)
    throws ODataException
{
    List<AddressEmailAddress> emailAddresses = service
        .getAllAddressEmailAddress()
        .filter(AddressEmailAddress.SEARCH_EMAIL_ADDRESS.eq(email))
        .execute();

    List<BusinessPartnerAddress> addresses = new LinkedList<>();
    for( AddressEmailAddress emailAddress : emailAddresses ) {
        addresses.addAll(
            service
                .getAllBusinessPartnerAddress()
                .filter(BusinessPartnerAddress.ADDRESS_ID.eq(emailAddress.getAddressID()))
                .execute());
    }

    List<BusinessPartner> businessPartners = new LinkedList<>();
    for( BusinessPartnerAddress address : addresses ) {
        businessPartners.add(service.getBusinessPartnerByKey(address.getBusinessPartner()).execute());
    }

    return businessPartners;
}
```