# SAP Cloud SDK for Javascript: Filter on Expanded Entities

Tags: javascript, typescript, sap-cloud-sdk, sap-successfactors

I know I am reopening an old one ([Perform filter on expanded entity with SAP Cloud SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56144905/perform-filter-on-expanded-entity-with-sap-cloud-sdk)), but it was a while ago and was referencing the Java version of the API used to consume an S/4 HANA service.

I'm testing the Javascript version of the API against the SuccessFactors OData API, which is indeed able to perform filters on expanded entities, like so:

```
<API_HOST>/odata/v2/PerPerson?$filter=personalInfoNav/firstName eq 'MARCO'&$expand=personalInfoNav&$select=personalInfoNav/firstName, personalInfoNav/lastName&$top=20
```

Translated into the SDK, it would be (TypeScript):

```
const personList: Array<PerPerson> = 
    await PerPerson.requestBuilder().getAll().top(20)
        .select(
            PerPerson.DATE_OF_BIRTH,
            PerPerson.PERSONAL_INFO_NAV.select(
                PerPersonal.PERSON_ID_EXTERNAL,
                PerPersonal.FIRST_NAME,
                PerPersonal.LAST_NAME,
                PerPersonal.GENDER
            )
        ).filter(PerPersonal.FIRST_NAME.equals('MARCO'))
         .execute({ destinationName: this.configService.get<string>('ACTIVE_DESTINATION') });
```

But this code does not compile because of the incompatibility of types for the filter function, which here expects a "PerPerson" type and not "PerPersonal".
I was not able to find anything about this.

Considering that the plain OData query works perfectly, anyone has been able to make this work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Perform filter on expanded entity with SAP Cloud SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56144905/perform-filter-on-expanded-entity-with-sap-cloud-sdk)

Comment: OData V2 is subject to the same rules no matter which type of Cloud Connector is used, Java or JS. It's a limitation of Odata implementation. So the question is no, filter is not possible.

Comment: I understand, but that's not the case. SDK or not, SuccessFactors OData V2 implementation applies filters on expanded entity and the URL i posted is an example of that. It really depends on the server side implementation, and SuccessFactors actually supports it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

I didn't initially understand that Successfactors offered this functionality on top of the protocol. There are two possible workarounds I can think of:

1. use `new Filter`, e.g.:

```
PerPerson.requestBuilder().getAll().top(20)
  .select(
   ...
  ).filter(
    new Filter('personalInfoNav/firstName', 'eq', 'MARCO')
  )
...
```

2. If this doesn't work, you can call `build` on the request builder instead of `execute`, which gives you the `ODataRequest` object from which you can get the URL, which you'd then have to manipulate manually. Then you should be able to use the `executeHttpRequest` function to execute this custom request object against a destination.

Let me know if one of these work for you!

---

**Original answer:**

filtering on expanded entities on OData v2 is only possible if the relationship between the two entities is 1:1. In the case the code would look like this:

```
PerPerson.requestBuilder().getAll().top(20)
  .select(
    PerPerson.DATE_OF_BIRTH,
    PerPerson.PERSONAL_INFO_NAV.select(
      PerPersonal.PERSON_ID_EXTERNAL,
      PerPersonal.FIRST_NAME,
      PerPersonal.LAST_NAME,
      PerPersonal.GENDER
    )
  ).filter(
    PerPerson.PERSONAL_INFO_NAV.filter(
      PerPersonal.FIRST_NAME.equals('MARCO')
  ))
...
```

If, however, the relationship is 1:n, filtering is not possible.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hello Dennis, and thank you. I know that in the OData model the relationship between PerPerson and PerPersonal is 1:N and from that came my question. I understand the generic nature of the SDK, but given the fact that SuccessFactors actually supports this kind of filtering, do you think is there a way to achieve it via any kind of workaround using the SDK?

Comment: Looks like I didn't read your question careful enough, my bad. I'll provide an update in my answer.

Comment: Hello Dennis, first option works like a charm for me! Thank you so much!